# Blender, rigging, vertex groups

Tags: blender

I have a problem with getting the vertex groups correct. Im following this tutorial: https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Tutorials/Your_First_Animation/2.Animation . I did everything it said about assigning the vertex groups. If i select them to see what are in the vertex group, everything is fine. But when im in pose mode and try to rotate the bones i still get the vertex groups that blender generated not the ones that i said it to use. I have blender v2.77. Can anyone give some advice?

Answer (score 1):

An armature bone deforms vertices that are in a **vertex group with the same name as the bone**.

If you want to manually make the vertex groups either remove the generated ones and rename your groups to match the bones, or rename the bones to match your vertex groups.